# Macbook Keeps disabling my Keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I have a Das Keyboard X50Q and as of late it will randomly go dark and no longer seem to have power going to it. I swap ports and even to my older Das Keyboard, but neither will work. I can use a BT Apple Keyboard and that works. If I restart my computer it does work for awhile.

I'm hoping there is a way I can identify why it is disabling it. Is there a particular log that can show the reason? Is there anyway to enable it without restarting?

**Hardware**: Macbook Pro 16inch 2019

- macOS Big Sur v11.5.2

Comment: Have you downloaded the latest version of the [Das Keyboard Q](https://www.daskeyboard.io/get-started/software/) software? What version of macOS is running on the MBP, and which model of the DSQ are you using?

Comment: I had switched to a new Macbook recently and forgot about the Q software. I just installed that and it started working... go figure.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you download the [latest version](https://www.daskeyboard.io/get-started/software/) of the Das Keyboard Q software. This will probably prove to be the solution to the problem.